# Investigate a solution that does not require actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match

Tags: github-actions

Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

My github workflow is as follow:-

```
name: Check the title of the PR for a Jira ticket ID

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: ['opened', 'edited']
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  verify_pr_links_jira:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check the title of the pull request
        uses: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2
        id: regex-match
        with:
          text: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
          regex: '([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)'

      - name: Throw an error if the pull request title is invalid
        if: ${{ steps.regex-match.outputs.match == '' }}
        run: |
          echo "::error::The Jira ticket ID must be included in the pull request title."
          exit 1
```

I had changed the version of checkout to v3 but still getting below error:-

Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/

Comment: I would suggest to use the `morrisoncole/pr-lint-action` https://github.com/MorrisonCole/pr-lint-action

Comment: Million thanks Matteo. let me try this workflow

Comment: cool, let us know if is working for you

Comment: No it is not working for me ? I am getting still below error:-      
verify_pr_links_jira
failed 17 hours ago in 3s
Search logs
Run echo "::error::The Jira ticket ID must be included in the pull request title."
Error: The Jira ticket ID must be included in the pull request title.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
0s

Comment: verify_pr_links_jira
The Jira ticket ID must be included in the pull request title.
verify_pr_links_jira
Process completed with exit code 1.
verify_pr_links_jira
Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16: actions-ecosystem/action-regex-match@v2. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-09-22-github-actions-all-actions-will-begin-running-on-node16-instead-of-node12/.
These are errors i am getting

Comment: This is my workflow file:-

name: Check the title of the PR for a Jira ticket ID

on:
  pull_request_target:
    types: ['opened', 'edited']
  workflow_call:

jobs:
  verify_pr_links_jira:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Check the title of the pull request
      - uses: morrisoncole/pr-lint-action@main
        
          echo "::error::The Jira ticket ID must be included in the pull request title."
          exit 1